# Access a "super"list?

Tags: python, list, super

Suppose I have

```
lyst = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

Is there a way to call *lyst* some way by only using one of the objects in the list (like *obj1*)?

Comment: Not unless that object explicitly has a reference to the list it is contained in. Whatever you are trying to do can certainly be done in a cleaner way. Can you add in more details?

Comment: So what if there is another list referencing `obj1`? Or any other type of object? `lyst` indices are *references*, and while there are ways to locate `lyst` from `obj1` this doesn't give you any way to distinguish between `lyst` and any other `list` object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341942/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-references-of-an-object-in-python This question explains quite abit about why it's not very feasible

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to do?