# Get the name of a list

Tags: python, list

I am not sure if this is possible in a simple way, but I am trying to get a name of a list object.

I did try with `__name__` but I get an error because the list object does not have an attribute `__name__`

Is even possible to get the variable name for a list, without subclass the list object and add the `__name__` attribute?

EDIT
This has nothing to do with the suggested duplicate.

This is my scenario:

```
cucumbers=[]
oranges=[]
salads=[]
...
masterlist=[cucumbers, oranges, salads]
```

At times I just get 2 lists, otehr times I get 5, so the masterlist has different number of lists in it, every time; and when I print it, I get only the values; so I don't know if the first list is cucumbers, oranges, salads or whatever it is.

I am trying to query the list so I can get the `variable name`, not the type of the object. so `print masterlist[1].name` will give me "cucumbers" or whatever is the name associated to that list.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the type (i.e. `list`) or the name of the variable?

Comment: This isn't going to really work because, while names have objects, objects _do not_ have names. An object, for instance, can have multiple names. Try this: `python3 -c "l = a = []; l.append(3); print(a)"`.

Comment: @MSeifert the name of the variable assigned to that object; so if I declare the list as `mylist=[]`, I would like to get the string "mylist" when I query the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a list of references of an object in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341942/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-references-of-an-object-in-python) the accepted can be slightly modified by changing value == 1 to value == your list, but you shouldn't do this, as it is very unpractical

Comment: objects can be bound to various names and if they are part of a container such as another list, no name at all (at least not directly). The best you could do is scan a namespace's variables and use `is` to see if you've found the right one.

Comment: Not the same thing; they have totally different scope @abccd. I declare a list as "mylist"; I save it in a list of lists; when I print each list in the master list, I want to get the name of each list, so I know which one is which.

Comment: Where is this `mylist` assignment done? Is it at module scope or perhaps in the locals of a function?

Comment: Use a `dict` (or if you have pandas you could use `pandas.DataFrame`) instead of a list. That allows you to assign a key (name) to the value (your sublist).

Comment: This sounds like a really strange thing to want to do. I would suggest that you have have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I did clarified the question. I don't believe it is anything complex to explain, but from your replies, it seems that my error is in using a list instead of a dictionary; I can use the dictionary key as the name of the list and the problem is solved. Although I am still curious to know why if I call "mylist", python knows which object is it, but if I query the object, Python has no clue about its assigned name

Comment: And please don't downvote just because you are not going for my question but for what you think I am asking.

Comment: Thanks @MSeifert, a dictionary will do; I guess it is too much to ask for the variable name to an object.

Comment: "Although I am still curious to know why if I call "mylist", python knows which object is it, but if I query the object, Python has no clue about its assigned name" The name holds a reference to the object (it *is* a reference to the object). The object does not hold a reference to the name. Anyway, an object can be referenced by many names... `x = y = z = a = b = foo = bar = []`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, I was not aware that the reference was not bi-directional. It make sense now why I can't get back the name, querying the object itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a dictionary instead:

```
masterdict={'cucumbers': cucumbers, 'oranges': oranges, 'salads': salads}
```

And instead of checking the name you iterate over the items of the dictionary:

```
for name, sublist in masterdict.items():
    print(name, sublist)
```

In case you want it ordered (and you don't have Python 3.6 where `dict`s are ordered) there is `collections.OrderedDict`.

---

The problem with getting the name for a variable is that variables reference python objects, but there can be many (differently named) variables referencing the same object. Also an object doesn't need a (visible) name to exist. For example if you have something like:

```
def func():
    cucumber = [1, 2, 3]
    return [cucumber]
```

Then the name `cucumber` doesn't exist anymore when the function finished. But the object (the `[1, 2, 3]` list) is still existing, but because it was wrapped in another list it's doesn't even have a "name" anymore. Just the outer list *could* have a name when the returned value was stored in a variable.

Comment: I was able to find something that reference to an object called global(); which hold all the variables; from what I understand. Although even querying that, will tell me if a variable name is in it, which is not what I need. I guess your solution is the most straightforward one; no need to complicate things if the solution is to use a dictionary. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, one could use `locals()` or `globals()` but you could get none, one or many results (and sometimes more results than you want because Python "shares" some objects). Also in the case you mentioned these lists are part of a "masterlist" and like the `func()` example shows the name might not even exist anymore at the time you want to query it.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on dicts being ordered in Python3.6. It's just a cpython implementation detail - it's not guaranteed in other implementations, or even future versions of 3.x (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Define 3 lists, and put them in a larger list:

```
In [1]: x = [1,2,3]
In [2]: y = ['a','b','c']
In [3]: z = []
In [4]: alist = [x, y, z]
```

display the larger list:

```
In [5]: alist
Out[5]: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
```

look at an element of that list:

```
In [7]: alist[0]
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3]
```

`alist` contains pointers to the other list objects, which we can check by looking at the `id`:

```
In [8]: id(alist[0])
Out[8]: 2895592076
In [9]: id(x)
Out[9]: 2895592076
```

But given an `id`, there isn't an easy way to find all the variables that point to that object.

A key thing to remember is that there is a difference between the variable `x`, its name, and the object that it references.

I could assign another variable to point to the list object:

```
In [10]: x1 = x
In [11]: id(x1)
Out[11]: 2895592076
```

I could also put these lists in a dictionary:

```
In [12]: dd = {'x': x, 'y1': y, 'zfoo': z}
In [13]: dd
Out[13]: {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'zfoo': []}
In [14]: id(dd['x'])
Out[14]: 2895592076
```

Note that the name or key in the dictionary does not have to match the name in the global namespace.

In sense just because I constructed `alist` with `[x, y, z]` does not mean that Python keeps a record of that statement. `alist` contains pointers to the objects referenced by `x`, `y` and `z`, but does not preserve any record the variable names that were used in that statement.

So what I think you are asking for is unrealistic in Python.

---

Switching the `x`, `y` references without changing `alist`:

```
In [15]: x, y = y, x
In [16]: alist
Out[16]: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
In [17]: x
Out[17]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
In [18]: x1             # x and x1 no longer point to the same object
Out[18]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: So if I get this right, I can retrieve the ID but not the name. But if I save the id when I create the list, I can compare that one against the output of id(). Cumbersome but may work. Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: Beware that it is possible to reassign a variable, without destroying or changing the objects referenced by a list.  I could for example, switch the `x, `y` references, `x, y = y, x` without changing the contents of `alist`.