# Python - Get all variable names for an object in global scope

Tags: python

I'll explain with an example:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = list_3 = list_1 # reference copy

print(magic_method(list_1))
# Should print ['list_1', 'list_2', 'list_3']

set_1 = {'a', 'b'}
print(magic_method(set_1))
# Should print ['set_1']
```

The requirement: return names of all variables pointing to the same reference. Is this at all possible with python?

I'm thinking something along the lines of iterating over `globals()` and `locals()` and equating `id`s. Is there anything better?

Comment: Are closures of interest as well?

Comment: @donkopotamus I don't think it needs to be _too_ complicated. I'm considering just global scope for now.

Comment: For global scope `globals()` is fine, no need to complicate it. And no need to compare ids when we have `is`.

Comment: Although you are not explicitly writing it, I understand that what you have is `def magic_method(obj): return [name for name, val in globals().items() if val is obj]`, and you'd like something more direct?

Comment: @jdehesa I could not effectively think of a solution, but that seems right. Will you write an answer? I am just looking at any possibilities to solve this.

Comment: What about the references under other containers, classes etc? `list_4 = [list_1, 0]; class A: foo = list_1`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I was not considering such scenarios, but if you feel that taking those into consideration would improve the quality of this question, I am all for it. However, if it results in a compromise of simplicity, it may not be worth it. What do you say?

Comment: If question is only about simple global references then the title should be changed. Also a dupe: [How can I get a list of references of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4341942/846892)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm also curious to know how an extension to the current solutions would be formulated for the container situation you mentioned. Have any ideas?

Comment: A recursive solution based on `gc.get_referrers`? But it is going to be very very tricky and most probably impossible. For example check this: http://ideone.com/rH1keq. `[[1, 2, 3], 0]` and `'list_4': [[1, 2, 3], 0]` are two separate entries, but are actually same references. There `'foo': [1, 2, 3]`, but who contains `foo`? Lastly for slots it simply says: `<__main__.A object at 0x2ae6efcf3ca8>`.

Comment: Check this lib for a basic implementation: https://github.com/mgedmin/objgraph/blob/master/objgraph.py#L417 But its output wasn't what I was expecting for the Ideone code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For global variables you can do:

```
def magic_method(obj):
    return [name for name, val in globals().items() if val is obj]
```

If you want local names too, you can use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
def magic_method(obj):
    import inspect
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        names = [name for name, val in frame.f_back.f_locals.items() if val is obj]
        names += [name for name, val in frame.f_back.f_globals.items()
                  if val is obj and name not in names]
        return names
    finally:
        del frame
```

And then:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = list_1

def my_fun():
    list_3 = list_1
    list_2 = list_1
    print(magic_method(list_1))

my_fun()
>>> ['list_3', 'list_1', 'list_2']
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I've updated the answer to include local variables too.

Comment: Note that this only works with local variables from the function that calls `magic_method`. If there are any more functions on the callstack they're simply ignored. You could loop through the callstack until `frame.f_back` returns `None`.

Comment: @Rawing Yes, you're right, I assumed only the locals from the direct caller would be of interest, but you could also inspect the whole stack like that.

Comment: if you call the function as magic_method(), will it return all the global methods of the environment?

Comment: @anitasp You mean like `magic_method()` without arguments? That wouldn't work, the function requires one argument as it is written. What do you mean by "all the global methods in the environment"?

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
def magic_method(var):
     names = filter(lambda x: globals()[x] is var, globals().keys())
     return names
```

`is` carries out a reference comparison. Add `list(...)` to the resultant expression if you are using Python3.

Comment: Should use `is` not `==`

Comment: ok, its not the same reference but the same value, change `==` for `is` to get the reference

Comment: The question was about the *same object*. Two distinct $100 bills are not the same piece of paper money.